# Unicode Text Displayed as numbers

Tags: mysql, jpa

I have a web application developed using JSF, JPA & MySQL. I recently moved the database and GlassFish server to a new machine. Initially there was text in a field labeled as @Lob, but now they are displayed as series of numbers.

For example, initially a text displayed as bbb, now displayed as 626262.

I didn't change any configuration of JSF or JPA.

How can I get data in mySQL database as text again.

The Entity Class

```
@Lob
String diagnosis;
```

JSF Page

```
 <h:outputLabel value="Diagnosis"/>
     <p:inputTextarea id="txtDxs" value="#{patientController.current.diagnosis}" style="width: 400px;">
 </p:inputTextarea>
```

Comment: How is this JSF related other then you 'using it'? I only see an entity. What if you print the value to a console, how does it look then? Also as numbers? Then it is not jsf related

Comment: Sorry. Updated the question.

Comment: But how does it display on the console? I mean when doing a sysout in the getDiagnosis()

Comment: System.out.print gives this                                                                            Info:   current.getDiagnosis() = 626262

Comment: How did you 'move' the database and server exactly?  What do you get when you query the table through the database client (outside of JPA?)

Comment: So it is at least not jsf related...